# Create types that transform an object literal of functions by removing a parameter

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function in TypeScript that takes an object literal of functions and returns an object literal with a very similar signature, only the first parameter has been dropped.  The goal here is that the typings are fully preserved, as it's easy to return an object literal where are the members have functions whose parameters are an unknown argument array.

The goal is the following:

```
const res = doSomething('someVal', { func1: (proxy, other: string) => proxy + other });
res.func1('other string') // This knows the "other" param is a string, and returns a string.
```

I am either able to create a result that compiles but the output literal has functions that are all argument arrays, or I get some kind of compiler error.  Below is one of my many attempts.

```
type Proxy<T> = {
  value: T;
};

/* 
 * The first parameter is always Proxy<T>.
 * The remaining parameters are what I want to keep in the return function.
 */
export type ProxyMethod<T, F extends (signalProxy: Proxy<T>, ...args: readonly any[]) => any> =
  F extends (...args: infer P) => infer R
    ? (args: P) => R
    : never;

/** This is the type of the object literal of functions that is the input */
export type ProxyMethods<T, K extends string> = {
  [Key in K]: ProxyMethod<T, (...args: unknown[]) => unknown>
};

/** Takes a ProxyMethod and creates a function without the first param. */
export type OutputMethod<F extends ProxyMethod<any, () => any>> =
  F extends ProxyMethod<infer T, infer F2>
    ? F2 extends ((signalProxy: Proxy<T>, ...args: infer P) => infer R)
      ? (...args: P) => R : never
    : never;

/** The intended output object literal */
export type OutputMethods<M extends ProxyMethods<any, string>> = { [Key in keyof M]: OutputMethod<M[Key]> };

function doSomething<T, const M extends Record<string, ProxyMethod<T, any>>>(
  value: T,
  methods: M
): OutputMethods<M> {
  /* do something */
  return methods as any; // stub, all I care about is the typings.
}

// Target signature provides too few arguments
doSomething('test', { help: (proxy: Proxy<string>, a: number) => `${a}`});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewB4gDwBUB8UC8UDeAUFFAG4CGANgK4QBcU6A3IQL4uED0AVFMb+gAW0AGYBLOAGdgUMOTjkAthGAQ4UMZKhUA7uRBb4yNFgB0-RsKhwIi8mIB2jgOaz5SlWq3zoOweRkASSg9BxlgBCgAawgIMA0HKGArG2BqOESRagcAY2AxBAdzKG5OQggkMAQ4cPBoIxQAWRVBBAATDAAaKAAxKArVBzatAApJMWcHKgaQBhmMTG7TZflnSQYbcjbCyhBtBxAAbQBdAEpcbHID7BxiXv6kQeGoEeXTVfWEkTVYc5xsRzfdQAJTuJAA-C8PnM-thQSQSAwHBBSGoODwBIJNBotMloKBIFAECIklYEAAjABWEDyUEoYlUCkoRJJWVy+UKuP8MmxeISYGoMlK5Uq1VqhJmzWS7UkXSgAGkHk8tNI4C4bgQ7od5RA9o4Fcc5ogmi12nLXis4GsGNkog4EDoHCdYVBbfbHZg2OjuAJyDFvLBjSApa02vswzlNqoA2y8gVEjoGa1BaTRBJpG4FIpTCUyhUqjUknUoAB5QUC4Ahs19AYQIaGINVjpXEDdEYuluYG53GuPOvPSWmjqAn7oboj9Q9ABMnoRUEh06V-dGYwmU0oMyNxgWS0t1q+PxgLonUGBpzBCMhFveVs+R4up6gSJRagvz9RcG9mOgjieEDDCDlimFLUrS9KMlQuYigW4rQGWwAVk2sqNEu9aBsYSGoC23SquqGr4FA2q6gk0S6sSUCNIapZAZWQ6oI0REgMc2DsIQhCxhyiTbAAyggyjJC4co5JyMgobWaHAjS1QdLhDjON0g7Sh0Y77CAXaYCMdwUDQ9CMJ0dz8aGnyNIQpwMPBiFDsh2BECQPBQNsUCSHxLQuFBJCpOkiSGTK2jeAcTBQJwnBOWk5LdFQzLBDkPjaOSgE8ly+LgC4kjmKwbHBYwqwqE5a4BOk0BgIgpBiG0EC4ggkTfDo2hWtQyhhJIhA8S5AlySMADk0bAJ13QEcIlBgAwIzFcYW4oKgsnOIs2hIg15JqC6AAGAAk+DkKwy2sKcTBAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mb30bW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - it would be nice if I didn't have to specify the type on the first parameter, but otherwise this looks great.  It would be great to explain what I was doing wrong, since your approach was much simpler.

Comment: "it would be nice if I didn't have to specify the type on the first parameter" I don't know if that's possible without currying as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w1ayYw); do you want that suggestion instead?  "It would be great to explain what I was doing wrong, since your approach was much simpler" That would require I dig through what you were doing, and since it was "one of [your] many attempts" I'm not sure what to say, that feels out of scope here... or if not, it expands the scope significantly and I'm not sure I'm willing to tackle it.  How would you like to proceed?

Comment: Don't worry about the explanation @jcalz.  I can figure that stuff out later, you can just answer the question as best you can, since it solves my query.  Thanks for the currying, that was what I was going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it this way:

```
function doSomething<T, M extends Record<keyof M, (p: Proxy<T>, ...args: any) => any>>(
  value: T,
  methods: M
): { [K in keyof M]:
    M[K] extends (p: Proxy<T>, ...args: infer A) => infer R ? (...args: A) => R : never
  } {
  return methods as any;
}
```

Here `doSomething()` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `T` of the `value` parameter and the type `M` of the `methods` parameter, where `M` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to have properties assignable to `(p: Proxy<T>, ...args: any) => any`; that is, to all be methods whose first parameter is of type `Proxy<T>`.  (A [recursive constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) of the form `X extends Record<keyof X, Y>` represents "all properties of `X` should be of type `Y`".)

Then the output type is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where each method type is transformed into a version without the first parameter.  That uses [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to extract the desired argument list `A` and return type `R`.

Let's test it out:

```
const y = doSomething('test',
  { help: (proxy: Proxy<string>, a: number) => `${a}` }
);
/* const y: {
    help: (a: number) => string;
} */
```

Looks good.

---

Unfortunately you can't get the callback parameter to be [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing); if you leave off the [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) you will get an implicit `any` error:

```
const y = doSomething('test',
  { help: (proxy, a: number) => `${a}` } // error!
  // ----> ~~~~~  Parameter 'proxy' implicitly has an 'any' type.
);
```

TypeScript's inference algorithm just isn't able to do simultaneous generic type inference and contextual typing inside a mapped type like this, at least not currently.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#52269](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52269), which links to [microsoft/TypeScript#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599), a request for general improvement of this sort of thing.

For now, if you want both generic type argument inference and callback parameter inference, you'll need to do make them non-simultaneous somehow.  One way to do that to [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) `doSomething`. So we replace the single function `(value, methods) => result` with the curried function `value => methods => result`:

```
function doSomething<T>(value: T) {
  return function <M extends Record<keyof M, (p: Proxy<T>, ...args: any) => any>>(
    methods: M
  ): { [K in keyof M]:
      M[K] extends (p: Proxy<T>, ...args: infer A) => infer R ? (...args: A) => R : never
    } {
    return methods as any;
  }
}
```

That lets the compiler infer `T` first, and *then* infer the callback parameter type contextually:

```
const y = doSomething('test')({ help: (proxy, a: number) => `${a}` }); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewB4gDwBUB8UC8UDeAUFFAG4CGANgK4QBcU6A3IQL4uEBm1AdgMbAAlgh5QAJggDKCALYRgAC0E8A5hgA0UALJQISYBB5iAzlABKEPgjhjUAawggEnbZoAUYBvGRosmgHSB5HAqxgzkPCAAlLjYESCYmG7EZFS0DOjqKXKKCCYMWoRRDPhQANoA0lDKUA5OLloAunQpJFqVjbr6hiZQHl6IKBiYAUEhYdU8nBBwUACCMTjYytOzZlAA-H2B-sGhDAux5lAMPBCkMymsBClw8tRwojkKeabkb5EsrISEVjzGwCgIFw4iksnkSlUbgA5AYAdCsiRSgoIJRPH0wIMQAMfKgAXBlCoRlByKdqDIAEYzRbYAAGABJ8ORWLSoN8oiwAPQAKigfwBQJKrSgKLRDDcpKgPHJVLgNKg+MJXyg3M5P35gIAXiCJNJnoSYXDgAiUsjUeiPFjNJLpZTqUcGUyWWyoJzObo4Ig4ABCFJuqAAWiDAewAD9w+GSDBguQcjMoNDMT5odUZGBKII+IJgJRgQp3iTRND4inQJB-EUWDxYxBjGByHxoABhB4EiBiG4pbj8IQiUF6iGE4ZuCg0eiMGJEEgkO7AB6ibsCYSiVA6PQGIymCxWGz2RzOVwYnFDPxQHZ7CbxeXxRJuZ6vArFYVI8pVGp1A9NFrTn-aDpdDden6WAsWGUZdnGBgVnjQ4lkmVZji2Nxz0g+Z5XWU5zkuX8XSnX9Z3nKB716At4hYH9vhIb4Ug1IEdTBfUoVhWtjSiNwzTFDErRJMk7TlB1GWZVlWA5H5WCAA)

Comment: I got this to work without having to provide the first parameter, but I can't paste the long playground link.  Here are my type declarations and function signature: **ProxyMethod<T>** = `(p: Proxy<T>, ...args: any) => any;`, **OutputMethod<P extends ProxyMethod<any>>** = `P extends (p: Proxy<any>, ...args: infer A) => infer R ? (...args: A) => R : never;`,  **OutputMethods<M extends Record<string, ProxyMethod<any>>>** = `{ [K in keyof M]: OutputMethod<M[K]> }`, **function doSomething<T, const M extends Record<string, ProxyMethod<T>>>** `(value: T, methods: M): OutputMethods<M>`